# Rotation is changing object's x axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make the object move around the scene and jump, but every time the object rotates it changes the axis of motion. How can I ensure that the rotation of the object does not influence its movement?

```
public float forca = 300f;
public Rigidbody2D Bola;
public float movdir = 5f;
public float moveesq = -5f;




// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Bola.AddForce(new Vector2(0, forca * Time.deltaTime), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        Bola.transform.Translate(new Vector2(movdir * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        Bola.transform.Translate(new Vector2(moveesq * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }
```

Comment: The Translate function has an overload that takes the space.
like this: transform.Translate(Vector3.one, Space.World);

Answer (score 1):

[`transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) takes an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) `relativeTo` with a default value `Space.Self` → movement in local X-axis

> If `relativeTo` is left out or set to `Space.Self` the movement is applied relative to the transform's local axes. (the x, y and z axes shown when selecting the object inside the Scene View.) If relativeTo is `Space.World` the movement is applied relative to the world coordinate system.

You can convert this into the global X-axis (independent from the objects orientation) by simply passing `Space.World` as last parameter:

```c#
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    Bola.transform.Translate(new Vector2(movdir * Time.deltaTime, 0), Space.World);
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    Bola.transform.Translate(new Vector2(moveesq * Time.deltaTime, 0), Space.World);
}
```

---

`AddForce` however takes world space coordinates anyway so there you already are independent of the objects orientation.

---

However, since there is a rigidbody involved you should not set the position using the `Transform` component at all. You should rather go through [Rigidbody2D.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html)

```c#
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    Bola.MovePosition(Bola.position + Vector2.right * movdir * Time.deltaTime);
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    Bola.MovePosition(Bola.position + Vector2.right * moveesq * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Yoi should this then rather also in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the problem! What kind of problem could happen if I kept using transform to move the object?

Comment: Collision might not get triggered and Physics will look unrealistic in certain circumstances

Answer (score 0):

**Multiply by `transform.forward`**

Currently your movement vectors are in absolute coordinates. You want them in local coordinates. The easiest way to do this is to multiple by `transform.forward` (for forward motion) and `transform.right` (for strafing motion).

Comment: Aren't both rather strongly dependent on the object's rotation?

Comment: @derHugo Perhaps I misunderstood the problem.